# How do I make this right content responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want this #content to be like this http://i.imgur.com/tunmL9B.jpg
 if it is on smaller screens.The #content should shrink according to the screen size

and if it is on large screens I want it to occupy as much as it can like this http://i.imgur.com/xB6bNsU.jpg .How do I do that?

```
#wrapper{
width:100%;
}

#sidebar{float:left;width:250px;}
#content{float:left;width:900px}


.post{
margin:0px 0px 25px 0px;
padding:0px 0px 15px 0px;
}

.post .date{
float:left;
width:50px;
height:50px;
font-size:18px;
margin:0px 25px 0px 25px;
line-height:24px;
text-align:center;
}


.post h2{
font-size:20px;
line-height:24px;
}
```

Thank You!

Comment: Please see this JSFiddle for full HTML
http://jsfiddle.net/7HgcA/

Comment: You should always try googling your problem before posting on this site. A google search for "responsive web design" will answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write

```
#sidebar{ float:left; width:250px;}
#content{ margin-left: 250px; }
```

The sidebar will mantain its width, while your content will grow along with the viewport width. Mediaqueries here are not really necessary, so this example works even on `IE<9`

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wn6fx/

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to use percentages for your widths, rather than setting width explicitly

Here is what you have now:

```
#sidebar{float:left;width:250px;}
#content{float:left;width:900px}
```

Here is how you could change it:

```
#sidebar{float:left;width:20%;}
#content{float:left;width:80%;}
```

This way, no matter what the screen size (or actually, the parent element's size), sidebar will always take up 20% of that (so `20% * 1000px = 200px` and `20% * 100px = 20px`, etc.) and content will always take up 80%.

**Media Queries**

Ultimately, however, this is just the starting point to being responsive. Imagine someone visits this page from a device that actually is only 100px wide. You'll probably want to start stacking elements instead of having them side-by-side. This can be accomplished with a media query:

```
@media all and (max-width: 360px) {
  #sidebar, #content {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

This media query will dynamically update the CSS of the corresponding elements for any viewing window that is <= 360px. In this case, it would make each one take up the full width of the screen.

This is just the beginning of making your websites responsive! Good luck!

**edit**

If you absolutely must maintain the 250px width for the sidebar, then [Fabrizio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21310717/how-do-i-make-this-right-content-responsive/21310795#21310810) is a better solution.

Comment: I don't want the sidebar to be "responsive"
I want it's width to fixed 250px. How do I make the #content responsive without changing the width of sidebar

Comment: Hmm...let me play around with that fiddle a little more and I'll update my answer

Comment: seems like this is what i was looking for...
Thanks!!

Comment: Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

I think most are missing what he is asking for.  He actually wants the text to shrink as the div shrinks.  I don't think that can be done with CSS the way you want it.  You can write media queries as the div steps down in size to change the size of the font but that is not a smooth effect.  You will most likely need to use javascript to achieve this effect.   BTW, this example that you linked is not really "responsive".  If you tried to view that on a phone it would be unreadable because the text would be like 6px.

Comment: I believe the reason most people are assuming he means responsive is because it's hard to understand why you would want the font size to change. I understand if it's just for changing header size, but for content, the size of the screen doesn't change what font size is best for the user to read.

Comment: I don't pretend to assume I know why either... was just stating it was being confused.  If you look at the example he linked it shows you what he wants.  I am assuming perhaps it is a school project or something because it would not be the correct way to make it responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sidebar{width:250px;float:left;}
content{margin-left:250px;}
```

Comment: how this is different from my answer?